# Can't build github page generic error

Tags: github, jekyll, travis-ci, github-pages

I am using travis CI to publish my jekyll site.

[Whole repo](https://github.com/trufavarela/openbazaar).

The relevant parts are:

.travis.yml

```
language: ruby
rvm:
- 2.3.3

before_script:
 - chmod +x ./script/cibuild # or do this locally and commit

# Assume bundler is being used, therefore
# the `install` step will run `bundle install` by default.
script: ./script/cibuild

# branch whitelist, only for GitHub Pages
branches:
  only:
  - gh-pages     # test the gh-pages branch
  - /pages-(.*)/ # test every branch which starts with "pages-"

env:
  global:
  - NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true # speeds up installation of html-proofer

sudo: false # route your build to the container-based infrastructure for a faster build

deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip-cleanup: true
  github-token: $GITHUB_TOKEN  # Set in the settings page of your repository, as a secure variable
  keep-history: true
  on:
    branch: gh-pages
```

My cibuild file is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e # halt script on error

bundle exec jekyll build
```

[This is the full log of the build](https://gist.github.com/trufa/53515c0092b2f5177edc63da781390d5).

Everything seems to be deploying ok, no errors.

But on Github I get:

[image]

The troubleshooting is no help.

**Just in case. I'm running `jekyll-assets` and I can't to build it with gh-pages directly, hence travis, see https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/189 specifically: https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/189#issuecomment-319070628**

I am really not sure how to process, the github error is of no help.

Answer (score 1):

If your site is already built by CI, you can add a `.nojekyll` file at the root of your code to instruct gh-pages not to generate but just publish you site.

Comment: i'll give it a spin. Thanks!

Comment: Heyy this seems to solve the issue partially!! Thanks a bunch. I'm still not sure exactly what it's doing. I'm also seeing a broken md file: https://trufavarela.github.io/openbazaar/ and not the generated html.

Comment: This seems to have to do with the fact that I have this [index.html](https://github.com/trufavarela/openbazaar/blob/master/index.html) at the root

Comment: I meant this file: https://github.com/trufavarela/openbazaar/commit/ee6336ac2ebac2ca6d5d90ba60bd49d67104a0aa#diff-eacf331f0ffc35d4b482f1d15a887d3b

Comment: Your CI is supposed to publish generated site. The content of **_site** folder and not the master branch code.

Comment: Hmm so the github branch gh-pages should just have the generated site? Is that generally done by Travis or is it a git config?

Comment: This is a Travis config that launch a deploy script. You can find examples by googling *jekyll travis*.